# SCNNode: fixing orientation from lookAt constraint

Tags: orientation, scnnode

Is it possible to fix a nodes orientation such that it no longer requires a lookAt constraint? I.e., "bake" the orientation of the node.

I'm making "bonds" (cylinders) between "atoms" (spheres). I place the cylinder node in a container node so as to re-orient its axes so the lookAt points the geometry's y-axis from one atom to another. So this all works but for two issues:
a) It seems to require delicate ordering in which these bonds are made else other bonds will pivot to undesirable positions. b) More importantly, it makes animation difficult.

So I'd like to use the lookAt to orient the bond then, somehow, get that orientation into a vector such that the bond becomes independant of the looked at node.

Edit: Here's a link to my ultimate answer. [swift: orient y-axis toward another point in 3-d space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384392/swift-orient-y-axis-toward-another-point-in-3-d-space)