# swift: orient y-axis toward another point in 3-d space

Tags: swift, vector, rotation, scenekit

Suppose you have two points in 3-D space. Call the first `o` for origin and the other `t` for target. The rotation axes of each are alligned with the world/parent coordinate system (and each other). Place a third point `r` coincident with the origin, same position and rotation.

How, in Swift, can you rotate `r` such that its y-axis points at `t`? If pointing the z-axis is easier, I'll take that instead. The resulting orientation of the other two axes is immaterial for my needs.

[image]

I've been through many discussions related to this but none satisfy. I have learned, from reading and experience, that Euler angles is probably not the way to go. We didn't cover this in calculus and that was 50 years ago anyway.

Comment: Well I'm confused. 3D points don't have rotation, they have x/y/z points along given axes. You're drawing 'r' as if it's a vector. Are you looking for the gradient between the origin and the target in the 'y' axis?

Comment: Sorry. These are meant to be vector representations. What I'm trying to orient is an SCNNode. I don't know how the term gradient would apply here. Thanks, Byrne

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! Incredibly simple when you add a container node. The following seems to work for any positions in any quadrants.

```
// pointAt_c is a container node located at, and child of, the originNode
// pointAtNode is its child, position coincident with pointAt_c (and originNode)

// get deltas (positions of target relative to origin)
let dx = targetNode.position.x - originNode.position.x
let dy = targetNode.position.y - originNode.position.y
let dz = targetNode.position.z - originNode.position.z

// rotate container node about y-axis (pointAtNode rotated with it)
let y_angle = atan2(dx, dz)
pointAt_c.rotation = SCNVector4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, y_angle)

// now rotate the pointAtNode about its z-axis
let dz_dx = sqrt((dz * dz) + (dx * dx))

// (due to rotation the adjacent side of this angle is now a hypotenuse)
let x_angle = atan2(dz_dx, dy)
pointAtNode.rotation =  SCNVector4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, x_angle)
```

I needed this to replace lookAt constraints  which cannot, easily anyway, be archived with a node tree. I'm pointing the y-axis because that's how SCN cylinders and capsules are directed.

If anyone knows how to obviate the container node please do tell. Everytime I try to apply sequential rotations to a single node, the last overwrites the previous one. I haven't the knowledge to formulate a rotation expression to do it in one shot.