# Set start and end points of SCNBox in swift

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have a long rectangular box and two points in SCNVector3 form I want to connect. Is there a simple way to set the start of the box to one point and the end of the box to the other?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. See if this helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384392/swift-orient-y-axis-toward-another-point-in-3-d-space

Answer (score -1):

Put the SCNBox at the midpoint of your two anchors. That's easy since its origin is its center.

Now, what have you done to compute the vector from one point to the next?

Comment: Im not sure I understand the question.