# 3D Line to connect two 3D Points

Tags: ios, swift, macos, 3d, scenekit

I have two 3D Points (Spheres) and I want to draw a line connecting them using a 3D Line (thin Cylinder). I am implementing this using SceneKit. So far I am able to draw the 2 points in 3D space with the cylinder line. I also have the length of the line calculated from the two points. Now I am looking for the right transformation matrix that would rotate the line such that it connects the two points.

I am planning to abstract a function that would take any two points and draw a line:

`func lineFor(point1 point1: SCNVector3, point2: SCNVector3) -> SCNNode`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I had a similar issue, `SCNLookAtConstraints` were limiting. They go waccy if you try to chain them in certain ways that force one of the nodes to rotate. They also don't archive. Here's how I solved my issue. I've used it to make tens of thousands of "chemical bonds". You  can easily make a factory function using it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384392/swift-orient-y-axis-toward-another-point-in-3-d-space

Answer (score 0):

Why not place the cylinder at one point, set its length and use a `SCNLookAtConstraint` so that it points at the second point?

Simon