# Rotate SCNNode to face point

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to rotate my object (SCNNode) to face the point where it's moving. I only move across x and y axis, so far I tried:

```
    // Action to move node
    let action1 = SCNAction.moveTo(SCNVector3(x: 4.0, y: 0.0, z: 6.0), duration: 3)
    // Get the tan angle:
    let angle = CGFloat(atan2(z, x))
    if angle - previousAngle > Pi {
        playerAngle += 2 * Pi
    } else if previousAngle - angle > Pi {
        playerAngle -= 2 * Pi
    }
    previousAngle = angle
    playerAngle = angle * RotationBlendFactor + playerAngle * (1 - RotationBlendFactor)
    let rot = playerAngle - 90 * DegreesToRadians
    flyNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: Float(rot))
```

It works for some target points but not for all.

I also try add to constraints array SCNLookAtConstraint, it rotates my node perfectly, but it stop my move to animation:

```
    let targerNode = SCNNode()
    targerNode.position = SCNVector3(x: -4.0, y: 0.0, z: -2.0)
    let con = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: targerNode)
    flyNode.constraints = [con]        
    let action1 = SCNAction.moveTo(SCNVector3(x: 4.0, y: 0.0, z: -2.0), duration: 3)
```

Can you help me out wit this, please?

Comment: Sounds similar to a problem I faced. See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384392/swift-orient-y-axis-toward-another-point-in-3-d-space

Comment: @bpedit thanks that what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution, though perhaps not the most elegant, is to apply your `moveTo` `SCNAction` to a node, and apply your `SCNLookAtConstraint` to a child of that node. This should enable both to operate without conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this: (it's objective C but it should be easy to convert)

```
float x, z;// these are your vars you assign these so you can delete this line


float offset = 0; // use this to offset your final output
                  // because your output might be off by 
                  // a quarter of a turn or so, or more
                  // but once you got the offset right
                  // than it will stay right
float aQuarterOfAturn = 1.570795;// since scenekit uses radians
                                 // this needs to be pi/2
                                 // if it was degrees it would be 90


if (x < 0) {
    offset += aQuarterOfAturn;// turn it to compensate for the lack of negetive x
    x *= -1;// convert x to positive so we can calculate it
}
if (z < 0) {
    offset += aQuarterOfAturn;// turn it to compensate for the lack of negetive z
    z *= -1;// convert z to positive so we can calculate it
}

xzDelta = x + z// add x and z

zPercent = z * 100 / xzDelta // so we can calculate how much percent z is

yRot = aQuarterOfAturn * zPercent / 100 // and finally convert it to a rotation

yRot += offset // add the offset and you can implement the rotation now
// a note, this code has not been tested you may need to offset it (above)
// and possibly multiply it by negitive 1

// if it works fine but the rotation is off by however many degrees than just offset it

// if it works fine but your move up and it rotates down than multiply it by -1
```

Let me know how it works!

Comment: so would the last line look something like ``SCNAction.rotateTo(x: x, y: yRot, z: z, duration: 1)``?